# how can i get all text with gecko c#

Tags: c#, geckofx

I use geckofx in my project c#, how can I get all the output :

```
Text 1
Text 2
Text 3
```

if the code example is like this :

```
<div class="A">
    <div class="B">
        <div class="C">
            <div class="D">Text 1</div>
        </div>

        <div class="C">
            <div class="D">Text 2</div>
        </div>

        <div class="C">
            <div class="D">Text 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
var a = this.Document.GetElementsByClassName("A").FirstOrDefault(); //this returns the parent A div (if it exists)
            if (a != null)
            {
                var text = a.TextContent; // and that gets the full text.
            }
```

Please bear in mind that 'GetElementsByClassName' returns a collection, because there can be many elements with the same class.